# How do I pass Button Value as a variable in Ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have a problem. I want to exchange certain data using PHP, MySQL and Ajax.

To do this I always have to pass the ID of a field to my backend, so I can continue working with this ID.

How do I pass the value from my button to my URL in Ajax?
What do I have to consider?
row['id'] is my variable (PHP)

HTML Code:

```
<a class='commentSikayet'>
  <button id='commentSikayet' name='commentSikayet' value='{$row['id']}'>
    Şikayet et
  </button>
</a>
```

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#commentSikayet").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'report_comment.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {bar: $("#bar").val()},
      success: function (result) {
        alert('Erfolgreich gemeldet.');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Your HTML structure is invalid. `<button>` should not be a child of `<a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there might be more than one data sets in your page I modified your example to the following snippet. Each buttons has a `data-id` attribute that identifies the current dataset (the id would be supplied through your PHP script as `$row["id"]`):

```js
$("body").on("click","button", function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault(); // prevent submitting a form ...
  let data={cmt_id: $(this).data("id"),
            value: $(this).prev().val()}
  $.post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments",data)
   .done(function (result) {
     console.log("Erfolgreich gemeldet:",result);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<div><input type="text" value="some text">
<button name="commentSikayet" data-id="123">Şikayet et</button></div>
<div><input type="text" value="some other text">
<button name="commentSikayet" data-id="124">Şikayet et</button></div>
<div><input type="text" value="more text">
<button name="commentSikayet" data-id="125">Şikayet et</button></div>
```

In your backend PHP script (taking the place of the above typicode-URL) you can pick up the values from the `$_POST` superglobal as

```
$_POST["cmt_id"]; // id value
$_POST["value"];. // actual text content
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am outputting my outputs via While loop.

Now I can only report my first comment.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, start a new question if you can't work it out by yourself. Comments are not really helpful for presenting actual questions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're listening for the *click* event on the button, you can access it via `this` in your handler function.

Add the name / value pair to your AJAX `data` option

```js
$("#commentSikayet").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post("report_comment.php", {
    bar: $("#bar").val(),
    [ this.name ]: this.value // add name / value in here
  }).done(function (result) {
    alert('Erfolgreich gemeldet.');
  });
});
```

This will include `commentSikayet=rowIdValue` in the POST request body which you access on the PHP side via...

```php
$rowId = $_POST["commentSikayet"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how do I call this in the other PHP file?

report_comment.php?page={valueID}

Comment: @pringItS if you have a follow-up question, then please ask it as a separate question, not just as a comment to an answer!

Comment: @pringItS sorry, I don't understand your question but I've added the corresponding PHP into my answer